# How and where to validate uniqueness of attribute/property in ASP.NET Core MVC using Entity Framework Core 6

Tags: entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I want to check, that users table records does not have specific email already stored.

If there is, then `ModelState.IsValid` returns false in controller action.

I understand need of unique constraint and I understand issues with race conditions. Those are not my concern right now.

At this point I just want to make `ModelState.IsValid` to return false after querying data in right place and making model invalid.

Should I implement such validation:

1. in `DbContext`?
2. in my entity classes (User / Company etc.)?
3. in `SomeCustomValidation` class?
4. directly in controller (since there I can already query the database...)
5. somewhere else...

And nice bonus would be create solution reusable across all entities :)

How should I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can custom validation attribute like below:

```
public class TestEmailAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value,
        ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var context = (YourDbContext)validationContext.GetService(typeof(YourDbContext));
        if(!context.User.Any(a=>a.Email==value.ToString()))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        return new ValidationResult("Email exists");
    }
}
```

Model:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [TestEmail]
    public string Email { get; set; }
}
```

View(Test.cshtml):

```
@model User
<form method="post" asp-action="Test" asp-controller="Home">   
    <div class="form-group">
        <input asp-for="Email" />
        <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Post"/>
</form>
```

Controller：

```
//GET render the Test.cshtml
public async Task<IActionResult> Test()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Test(User user)
{
    if(!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(user);
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Your example did work, although there are some `null` checks required to get rid of warnings, also I would like that `TestEmailAttribute` class would be `UniqueAttribute` that handles dynamically `model` and `attribute`. Since all of that is inside `validationContext`, I gues I can do that! Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

better way is that you check it before every insert or update by :

```
if(db.Table.Any(x => x.UniqueCloumn == newValue))
    error = "this record is already exist"
else
{  
    db.Table.Add(newObject);
    db.Savechanges() 
}
```

also there is some approach for reusable code that I do not recommend :
https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1143215/Validate-a-Unique-Constraint-at-dbContext-Validate